# Can't enable Flash in Chrome 63.0.3239.84

Tags: google-chrome, 17.10, flash

Whenever I try to watch NBC Live Sports I get a message telling me to restart Chrome to enable Adobe Flash Player. Restarting doesn't help. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10. 
Any idea how I can enable Flash Player in Chrome?

Comment: Does your Flash Plugin version show up at [this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/)?

Comment: That page shows the latest version as 27.0.0.187, but how can I tell what version of Flash I have installed?

Comment: Don't you see a "Version information" box which says "You have version 27.0.0.187 installed"?